# QGIS atlas-generation: Is it possible to preserve the map section?

Tags: qgis, atlas

My aim is to generate several maps with the atlas function in QGIS 2.4 (win7 64) showing the same map section and scale. However, each generated atlas map shows a slightly different map section (not scale) according to the position of the features of the coverage layer. I want only the displayed features to change, not the map section. I can't see a possibility to 'fix' the map. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you uncheck the "controlled by atlas" check box from your map item's properties then the map will keep exactly the same extent and scale for every atlas feature.